# Atribuição de valor a variável

Tags: delphi, variáveis

Tenho duas variáveis globais, que vamos chamar de **A** e **B**, quando faço a seguinte atribuição:

```
A:= 5;
B:= A;
```

Toda vez que mudo o valor de **A**, o valor de **B** também muda. Se eu fizer

```
A:= 10
```

**B** passa a ser 10 também. Como eu posso mudar o valor de **A** sem alterar o valor de **B**?

Comment: Pode dar mais contexto. Isto é para acontecer não.

Comment: Como estao declaradas as variaveis A e B?

Comment: Precisa ver se não tem um "var" em função, algo assim. Da forma como está a pergunta, não dá pra reproduzir o problema. Se puder [edit] o post com um [mcve], fica mais fácil de ter uma soluçao.

Comment: Este comportamento só acontecerá se a variável B for um ponteiro de inteiro e assim mesmo a sintaxe de atribuição seria diferente.

Comment: Tmc, o que você esta pedindo independente do código que venha antes é meio sem fundamento, pois no código você mesmo esta dizendo que B = A... Ou você muda essa regra ou coloca um IF para verificar se realmente quer atribuir o valor de a em B.

Answer (score 2):

Em Delphi o código é executado linha a linha logo se tiver o seguinte código:

```
A := 5;
B := A;
showmessage('A=' + IntToStr(A) + '; B=' + IntToStr(B));
```

> **Mensagem:** A=5; B=5

Está a atribuir o mesmo valor de **A** á variavel de **B**.
Para **B** ter um valor diferente de **A** basta para isso remover a atribuição da mesma "`B := A;`" exemplo de código:

```
A := 10;
//B := A;
B := 62;
showmessage('A=' + IntToStr(A) + '; B=' + IntToStr(B));
```

> **Mensagem:** A=10; B=62

Não sendo a opção mais correta (dependendo dos casos) pode ainda reatribuir o valor da variavel **B**, exemplo:

```
A := 10;
B := A;
showmessage('A=' + IntToStr(A) + '; B=' + IntToStr(B));
```

> **Mensagem:** A=10; B=10

```
B := 62;
showmessage('A=' + IntToStr(A) + '; B=' + IntToStr(B));
```

> **Mensagem:** A=10; B=62

Existe ainda uma ultima opção que é atribuir um novo valor a **A** da seguinte forma, exemplo:

```
A := 5;
B := A;
A := 10;
showmessage('A=' + IntToStr(A) + '; B=' + IntToStr(B));
```

> **Mensagem:** A=10; B=5

Answer (score -3):

Você está declarando que **B** é igual a **A**, logo quando você muda **A**, vai mudar **B**.

```
A:= 5;
B:= A; //Aqui que você declara que B é igual a A
```

Uma coisa que você pode fazer é declarar **B** como 5 e mudar o valor de **A**

```
A:=5;
B:=5;
A:=10;
```

Assim, **B** não esta definido como **A**, logo não é alterado.